# Javascript variable message

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some code that creates a map and writes a variable to the console after a polygon has been created. I want to see the value of the variable length in the body of the page after the map. Can anyone please help? thanks. Here is a code snippet;

```
    //add event listener for completion of your polygon
                google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
                    //get the coordinate array of your polygon
                    var path = polygon.getPath();
                    //calculate area
                    var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(path);
                    //calculate length
                    var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path);
                    //print the area & length
                    console.log('Polygon Area: ' +  area/1000000 + ' km sqs');
                    console.log('Polygon Length: ' +  length/1000 + ' kms');

                });

                //add event listener for completion of your polyline
                google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', function(polyline) {
                    //get the coordinate array of your polyline
                    var path = polyline.getPath();
                    //calculate length
                    var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path);
                    //print the length
                    console.log("Polyline Length: " +  length/1000 + " kms");
                });
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()">
    <b>Calculating Length and Area</b><br/>
    <div id="mapDiv"/>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the issue with the posted code? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [The posted code seems to work fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k9LxdfL8/1/)